# Changing texture slot mapping size has no effect

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to flip image vertically by changing Texture slot > Mapping > Size property.
[image]

But when i changing X, Y, Z values, the textures on the object is still not flipped. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe I should do something after I changed the values?

Answer (score 2):

why you expect changing **size** or **offset** values to be affecting **rotation** or **flipping**? Btw, if you use "UV" as mapping coordinates, you should use a  UV map, which would give better texturing control on your object... (later on this)

If you try, eg, "global" coordinates (projection "flat" in my example using a plane mesh):

[image]

you can invert X/Y slots and get the texture rotated...

[image]

is this what you want?

If you used UV mapping (you have to "UV unwrap" before your mesh in edit mode) instead:

you could assign your texture to that UV map, in the UV/image editor (on the left below), then set the UV mapping type using your unwrapped UV:

[image]

then, rotating the UV map in the UV/image editor, you can use the UV map and rotate, scale, modify it, to adjust your texture precisely, to your mesh:

[image]

Most people use UV mapping because it gives total freedom, but the other (old) way still works, it is just different.